# Oracle Query for grouping and percentage of Runs

Tags: oracle

I am looking for query that would give the totals and the percentage of runs based on a field .
I am able to get the query using two select statements and then a  final where i join them based on Country Field .
Below is the raw data.

[image]

I am trying to get output where runs grouped by country and class along with the percentages of each class in the country.
Thanks in advance for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use below sql to achieve your purpose.

1. I use grouping sets option within group by clause to make Oracle generate the require subtotals
2. I use ratio_to_report analytic function to calculate the Percentage column
3. Finally, I format the result according to your expected output format using ROUND function.

```sql
select COUNTRY, CLASS, RUNS
    , NVL2(
        PERCENTAGE
        ,   ROUND ( PERCENTAGE, case when COUNTRY = 'Grand Total' then 2 else 0 end ) || '%'
        ,   null
    ) PERCENTAGE
from (
    select  
        decode( grouping(t.COUNTRY), 1, 'Grand Total', t.COUNTRY ) as COUNTRY
    ,   t.CLASS
    ,   sum(t.RUNS) runs
    ,   100 * RATIO_TO_REPORT(
                case 
                    when t.CLASS != 'Total(Batsman+Bowler+Allrounder)' then sum(t.RUNS)
                    else null
                end
                )   OVER (PARTITION BY t.COUNTRY) PERCENTAGE
    ,   grouping_id(t.COUNTRY, t.CLASS) grp_id /*just added for sorting in the outer view*/
    from Your_table t
    group by grouping sets ((t.COUNTRY, t.CLASS), (t.CLASS))
)
order by grp_id, COUNTRY, PERCENTAGE
;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1437e0b464bb8a624c9b815eba88ae7a)

Comment: Hi MDO ,thanks for the details and the query help .I was able to use the above query and i had to do  minor changes for the output needed on my end .

Comment: Hi @krash, Thanks for your question.
Glad to see I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query -

```
SELECT T.Country, T.Class, T.Runs, ROUND((T.Runs/TOT_RUNS.Runs)*100, 2)||'%' Percentage
  FROM (SELECT Country, Class, SUM(Runs) Runs
          FROM YOUR_TABLE
         WHERE UPPER(Class) IN ('BATSMAN', 'BOWLER', 'ALLROUNDER')
         GROUP BY Country, Class) T
  JOIN (SELECT Country, SUM(Runs) Runs
          FROM YOUR_TABLE
         WHERE UPPER(Class) IN ('BATSMAN', 'BOWLER', 'ALLROUNDER')
         GROUP BY Country) TOT_RUNS ON T.Country = TOT_RUNS.Country
 UNION ALL
SELECT Country, Class, SUM(Runs), NULL
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE UPPER(Class) IN ('TOTAL(BATSMAN+BOWLER+ALLROUNDER)')
 GROUP BY Country, Class
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Grand Total', 'Batsman', SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(Class) = 'BATSMAN' THEN Runs END),
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(Class) = 'BATSMAN' THEN Runs END)
      /SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(Class) IN ('BATSMAN', 'BOWLER', 'ALLROUNDER') THEN Runs END)*100, 2) || '%'
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Grand Total', 'Bowler', SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(Class) = 'BOWLER' THEN Runs END),
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(Class) = 'BOWLER' THEN Runs END)
      /SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(Class) IN ('BATSMAN', 'BOWLER', 'ALLROUNDER') THEN Runs END)*100, 2) || '%'
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Grand Total', 'Allrounder', SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(Class) = 'ALLROUNDER' THEN Runs END),
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(Class) = 'ALLROUNDER' THEN Runs END)
      /SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(Class) IN ('BATSMAN', 'BOWLER', 'ALLROUNDER') THEN Runs END)*100, 2) || '%'
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Grand Total', 'TOTAL(BATSMAN+BOWLER+ALLROUNDER)', SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(Class) = 'TOTAL(BATSMAN+BOWLER+ALLROUNDER)' THEN Runs END),NULL
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: Hi Ankit,Thanks for the help.